# Connecting Android device to Apache server

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache

I have created a database and trying to access it using php. I execute these scripts from my phone. Now the issue is that when I try to perform any operation on the DB from the real device *(my MOBILE PHONE)* it says **"unfortunately Closed"** but works fine from the virtual device.

URL for real android device:

```
[http:// 127.0.0.1:8888 //android_connect/get_product_details.php]
```

URL for the virtual device:

```
[http:// 10.0.2.2 /android_connect/get_product_details.php]
```

Comment: You are trying to test on your local PC server? You need to use your PC IP address then.

Answer (score 0):

The `127.0.0.1` is a loopback address so the android device or any other computer **will not able to connect** to it. Get a webserver (there's a lot freely available to test PHP scripts) , drop all the files in there  and you will be able to access it.

say.. `http://somefreewebhost.com/android_connect/get_product_details.php`

*Alternatively...*

If you are using a webserver like `WAMP`, you will have an option called "Put Online". Go to your command prompt and type "ipconfig" and note down that IP address and you can even use that (*provided if you are not behind any firewall*)

Comment: I am using EasyPhp. is it possible to do the same using this ?

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar, Never tried as WAMP is better than that. Why not use a webserver instead ? There are a lot freely available.